# Is it possible to do TextView/EditView with permanent copy/paste cursors

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, fragment, copy-paste

I am designing an application, where I have `fragment` with text to selection and button. And I need to transmit selected text to next `fragment`, when I click on `Button`. Also, text must be always selectable ( with two cursors for selection). I try use `TextView` to do it: I make my TV selectable:

```
tvMain.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

And now I can call cursors by long pressing on TV. But these is not, what I'm expecting. Cursors must be always visible and never hiding from text. Any ideas, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EditText with null background so that it look like TextView and do something like this:

```
tvMain.selectAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText1);

int selectionStart = text.getSelectionStart();
int selectionEnd  = text.getSelectionEnd();
```

And then get a substring from the start to the beginning

```
String selectedText = text.getText().toString().substring(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
```

You CAN use it with TextView too.

Comment: I know about this capabilities. But I need something else: need to have permanent copy\paste cursors, and after use your answer.